# h2o models on Azure ML Containers

Tags: containers, h2o, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a requirement to deploy h2o models on Azure . I have successfully handled sklearn models but for sklearn the dependencies in my view are easier . For h2o the java runtime dependency is my bottle-neck.

Will the container that i create will have java runtime ?> Else what are the suggested strategies ?

Should I go for a VM instead ?

Thanks,

Comment: Hello Rajesh, there are official H2O Docker images available on docker hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/h2oai/h2o-open-source-k8s - feel free to use those. For experimenting, I recommend using the "latest" tag. `docker run h2oai/h2o-open-source-k8s`.

Those images are based on openJDK 11. Make sure to read the README about memory usage.

Comment: Hi Pavel,Thanks so much . Just the thing I was looking for .

Comment: Hi @PavelPscheidl if I may ask one more question , is it possible to add my trained models to this docker and use them for prediction ?

Comment: Hello @PavelPscheidl I asked this a separate question below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62655956/importing-model-file-into-docker-container-h2o